Getting A blank Page when Added Route in React
App.JSX
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Home from './pages/Home/Home'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <BrowserRouter>
         <Routes>
           <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} />
         </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Home.jsx
import React from 'react'
import Header from '../../components/Header/Header'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home

I want to load the Navbar and the Header file but it is not loading just showing me the blank page.

The Navbar should render regardless, and Header will be rendered when Home is rendered when you are on path "/home". What path are you on when testing? Is the entire page completely blank? Or just the content rendered by the router? How are you running the app? Can you [edit] to provide more debugging details?

Open the developer tools; I guess there will be an error.

Also share how is your project structured, are you sure the Header component ubication is right?

It got solved what I did was I just added both the lines in the Roue function first was
<Route path='/home' element={} />
and second was this
<Route path='/' element={} />

You might need to add index to the nested route:
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <BrowserRouter>
         <Routes>
           <Route index path='/home' element={<Home />} />
         </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}


